# MySQL Query - pass argument into same query

Tags: mysql

I would like to combine all issues that have same ID and show who is affected without showing all the people affected with the same issue (multiple lines).

```
SELECT
 plugin_id as 'Plugin id',
 cve as CVE,
 cvss3_base_score as cvss3_base_score,
 risk as Risk,
 COUNT(DISTINCT(Host)) as 'Affected Unique Hosts',
 Name,
 plugin_family as 'Plugin Family',
 last_seen as 'Last Seen',
 vulnerability_state as 'Vulnerability State'
from tenable_network
GROUP BY plugin_id
ORDER BY plugin_id DESC
```

```
Fetch Assets Query
============
SELECT
 role_id,
 Host,
 Name,
 Synopsis,
 Port,
 Protocol,
 OS,
 FQDN 
FROM tenable_network
WHERE plugin_id='90317'
GROUP BY Host
```

As you can see, I can group all roles that have plugin_id 90317 (issue)

Is there a simple way to pass the argument within the query?

Thanks

Comment: not at all clear what you are asking.  please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table tenable_network;` and some sample data and desired results for that sample data that illustrate what you are asking to do

Comment: Even with all the information, that ysth is asking for, I probably wouldn't understand your question. The bit that confuses me is this: _"Is there a simple way to pass the argument within the query?"_. What do you mean? You just exactly did what you're asking: You used your keyboard and typed the number 90317.

Comment: Are you perhaps interested in the GROUP_CONCAT function?  GROUP_CONCAT(Hosts) in the select clause would give you a comma separated list of Hosts in your result.  You would want to GROUP BY plugin_id, I think, if this is the case.